# Matching file names in Unix

Tags: unix

I have two folders. Some of the files are similar names.

In one folder the names are X-Y-1234.O
The second one the names are Z_1234.O

I am trying to match the files with the same numbers (1234). Sometimes it it is alphanumeric.

Answer (score 0):

Not very clear what you want to do with the files.

Maybe you can pair them up with `paste` and process substitution, and pipe the pairs to a `while` loop like this:

```
paste <(ls dir1/*) <(ls dir2/*) | while read a b; do echo diff $a $b; done
```

If the files don't line up exactly in the two directories, you could add filters in the subshells, for example:

```
paste <(ls dir1/* | grep '\.O$') <(ls dir2/* | grep '\.O$') | ...
```